# I think I've been hacked, is there a way to tell?

Tags: networking, security, wireshark

Someone that I game with now and then keeps saying things that make me think he's hacked me. For example I might be looking at something on the net between games, and he'll bring it up or say something related. The first few times I brushed it off as coincidence, but it's happened too many times now for it to be just that, and it's been specific things that couldn't have just been flavour of the day on Youtube or what not.

Is there a way I can tell for sure? I've looked at Wireshark to see if that might be able to help but I'm struggling to interpret the data that it shows. What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot you could look for, and it's typically not going to be something simple.  Entire books have been written about this topic.

Your time is better spent assuming you are hacked and acting accordingly, because you have to do that anyway.

And your computer may not even be involved, it's possible this person may have access to your Google, Facebook, or Instagram account which could reveal much of anything you are searching for online or have liked.  Another common point of entry are remote access programs like VNC, LogMeIn, TeamViewer.  It's also possible your router is hacked and not your computer, or another computer on your network.

Take some time and make a list of every online service you use, or any program that requires you to make an account, or anything you've ever created an account for.  Delete or deactivate any accounts you don't use anymore.  Change passwords to the rest.  Use strong passwords that can't be found in a dictionary.  Never enter your password on a site if your browser says http (not https) or "Not Secure".

Regarding your computer, the safest thing to do is backup any important data, reinstall your operating system from scratch, install an antivirus/security solution, and start over from a known "good" point.  If you don't want to do that, you can do this, assuming Windows:

- Look at Programs and Features and uninstall anything that you don't need, don't use anymore, or looks suspicious.  Do not remove Microsoft components or runtimes.
- Download the free version of CCleaner, and use its Startup feature to disable anything that automatically starts that looks unneeded or suspicious.
- Create a new user account, move your data to it, and delete your old user account.
- Download the free versions of SUPERAntiSpyware and/or Malwarebytes, run a virus scan, and delete anything it tells you.
- Apply all latest updates for Windows and other programs you use, especially Adobe products and Java if you use that.

Regarding your router, if it's a router you purchased and you have access:

- Log in to your router and note all settings.
- Look for a factory reset function and factory reset the router.
- Log back in to router and use any firmware update function to ensure it has the latest firmware.
- Ensure your Wifi passwords are strong.
- Disable any features in your router that you don't use, like any cloud or media services.
- Disable uPnP unless you know you have a need for it.

Comment: In line with @LawrenceC 's statement, even a web-enabled room-monitor or smart TV could leak information.